# condition for the existence data in java servlet

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets

i have created a ResuktSet as follows:

```
ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("Select * from category where category_name='"+name+"'");
```

I use a postgresql dataBase.
How can make the condition in servlet on the existence of data, ie, if the category name does not exist it can be added, else is no need to add?

Comment: You will have to hope your category isn't named `O'Hare`

Comment: yes, it doesn't exist in database